# Update duration and restart CircularCountDownTimer with new duration

Tags: flutter, countdown

I'm having problem using the circular_countdown_timer library to change the duration time and restart the countdown with the updated time. Here's my code:

```
int duration = 6;
CountDownController _controller = CountDownController();

CircularCountDownTimer countDownWidget() {
  return CircularCountDownTimer(
    duration: duration,
    controller: _controller,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
    color: Colors.orangeAccent,
    fillColor: Colors.red,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    strokeWidth: 10.0,
    textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 22.0, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    isReverse: true,
    isTimerTextShown: true,
    onComplete: () {
      print('Countdown Ended');
      setState(() {
        duration = 9;
        _controller.restart();
      });
    },
  );}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have added optional **int** parameter in `restart` method of `CountDownController` to easily achieve your requirement
**i.e** `_controller.restart (duration: 20);`

In the above statement, the named parameter `duration` is updated duration for countdown.

You can find it in latest version **0.0.7** of [circular_countdown_timer](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_countdown_timer)